# Chart Js doesn't update the values in the first load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am trying to use Vue-ChartJs to modify the chart by updating its value according to firebase. Unfortunately, it doesn't display the updated values when it is first loaded. If I render some other component and come back and then re-render the chart component from the navbar, then it works perfectly fine.

```
// Initialize Firebase
let app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let postss = app.database().ref('posts');
var topics = [];

function gotData(data){
 for(var z = 0; z < topics.length; z++){
   topics[z] = 0;
 }
let categori = data.val();
let keys = Object.keys(categori);
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    let k = keys[i];
    let categoriezz = categori[k].categories;
for(let dates = 0; dates < categoriezz.length; dates++){
      if(categoriezz[dates] == "Politics"){
        topics[0]++;
      }
      else if(categoriezz[dates] == "Travel"){
        topics[1]++;
      }
      else if(categoriezz[dates] == "Software"){
        topics[2]++;
      }
      else if(categoriezz[dates] == "History"){
        topics[3]++;
      }
    }
      //console.log(categoriezz,politics,travel,software,history);
}
console.log(topics[0],topics[1],topics[2],topics[3]);
}

function errData(err){
console.log(err);
}

export default {
  extends: Pie,
  props: ['chartdata', 'options'],
  mounted () {
    postss.on('value', gotData, errData);
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['Politics','Software','History','Travel'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Topics',
          backgroundColor: ['red','green','brown','blue'],
          data: [topics[0],topics[2],topics[3],topics[1]]
        }
      ]
    }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`topics` need to be Vue's data to make it reactive. Please try:

```
 export default {
    extends: Pie,
    props: ['chartdata', 'options'],
    data() {
        return {
            topics: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        }
    },
    mounted () {
      postss.on('value', this.gotData, errData);
      this.renderChart({
        labels: ['Politics','Software','History','Travel'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Topics',
            backgroundColor: ['red','green','brown','blue'],
            data: [this.topics[0], this.topics[2], this.topics[3], this.topics[1]]
          }
        ]
      }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
    },
    methods: {
        gotData(data)  {
            let topics = [0, 0, 0, 0]
            let categori = data.val();
            let keys = Object.keys(categori);
            for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
                let k = keys[i];
                let categoriezz = categori[k].categories;
                for(let dates = 0; dates < categoriezz.length; dates++){
                    if(categoriezz[dates] == "Politics"){
                        topics[0]++;
                    }
                    else if(categoriezz[dates] == "Travel"){
                        topics[1]++;
                    }
                    else if(categoriezz[dates] == "Software"){
                        topics[2]++;
                    }
                    else if(categoriezz[dates] == "History"){
                        topics[3]++;
                    }
                }
                //console.log(categoriezz,politics,travel,software,history);
            }
            this.topics = topics
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have found out that it automatically assigns the values that we were appointed as 0,0,0,0. If you change those values, it will appoint them as changed. This gotData function has to be able to change those values in the first load. How is that even possible?

Comment: It also gives this error : [Vue warn]: data functions should return an object: